# About the 'who' command & it's Output on '14.04 TrustyTahr'

Tags: 14.04, command-line, display, lightdm, who

I have a question that arose in my
mind after upgrading to 14.04 TrustyTahr from 12.04 PrecisePangolin. The
question pertains to the 'who' command, and its output. On previous editions of Ubuntu the output the who command would read what tty was used to login and initiate the system and lightdm, for example:

```
:~$ who
geo      tty7     thedate (:0)
geo      pts/n    thedate (:0.0)
```

But on 14.04 TrustyTahr, when I run the who command my output yields:

```
:~$ who
geo      :0       thedate (:0)
geo      pts/n    thedate (:0.0)
```

On both editions the vt7 handoff is happening in /boot, and on TrustyTahr
my XDG_VTNR variable is 7 when I login via lightdm; but tty7, nor vt7 is 
printed to the utmp file. This annoyed me for months, I finally wrote a c++ program, that incorporates the popen function, as a supplement to the who command in order for the who command to display the current XDG_VTNR with a tty coefficient e.g.:

```
geo      tty7         2015-06-04 20:54 (:0)
geo      pts/0        2015-06-04 20:54 (:0.0)
```

None the less why has this changed? And also is mine the only one like that, cause I downloaded this around May of last year, and I might have gotten a bunk iso or something, everytime I run the who command it makes me think of that Beastie Boys song: Sabotage (jk its not the bad).

Comment: I'm on 14.04. Just now I went to tty1 and ran `startx $(which gnome-shell)`. The output of `who` reported tty1 and :0 . I guess your particular machine is experiencing a bug of some sort

Comment: update the question with $who --version

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading the package that contains the `who` command; even if you did use a strange version of the ISO to install from, an update should replace it:

Find out what package owns `who`:

```
which who    # find out where 'who' binary is
dpkg -S /path/to/who
```

Then:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <package name from dpkg -S command>
```

If it still doesn't work, try a different shell with no environment (to get rid of any wonky environment variables, setups, bash-specific junk, etc.):

```
env -i /bin/dash
$ who
```

If it works in a bare shell, then the problem is likely a weird alias definition in a bashrc, or something similar.

Also, does `who --all` work?